# Guide using for loop on python web scraping class

Tags: python, for-loop, email, web-scraping

I have a python bot for email extraction which takes one query and google search using this single query and then returns a list of found emails using the query, I need to consider the result as one, and use **for loop for multiple queries** and insert the list of found emails as a string into each cell. Please any idea how this can be done.
This is the **scraping** code

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Request
from googlesearch import search
import re
from scrapy_selenium import SeleniumRequest
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# create class to extract email ids
class email_extractor(CrawlSpider):
     
    # adjusting parameters
    name = 'email_ex'
 
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(email_extractor, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.email_list = []
        **self.query = " 'Students with infectious disease, Rome, Italy' "**

    def start_requests(self):
        for results in search(self.query, num=10, stop=10, pause=2):
            yield SeleniumRequest(
                url=results,
                callback=self.parse,
                wait_until=EC.presence_of_element_located(
                    (By.TAG_NAME, "html")),
                dont_filter=True
            )

    # extracting emails
    def parse(self, response):
        EMAIL_REGEX = r'[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+'
        emails = re.finditer(EMAIL_REGEX, str(response.text))
        for email in emails:
            self.email_list.append(email.group())
 
        for email in set(self.email_list):
            yield{
                "emails": email
            }
 
        self.email_list.clear()
```

Currently, this work for a single query, want to loop over multiple queries, any idea please?

Comment: FYI ‘scrapping’ means throwing away - you’re doing __scraping__

Answer (score 0):

I don't think multiple queries will do instead I think you should create a query using join function to create a single query with multiple datas. Since I don't know what database you are using you should look for an information wherein you can count the number of rows in your query and make each rows into tuples/lists then create your loop out of it.